# Assigning callbacks for a $.post call in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this script that works pretty well, but it keeps triggering the "error" callback, even though there is no error:

```
$(".comment-form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this),
        text = $form.find('textarea').val();
        url = $form.attr('action');

    $.post(url, { comment: text,
        beforeSend: function() {
            alert("before send");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error"); 
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);    
        }
    });
});
```

Am I using the callbacks incorrectly here? Shouldn't the error callback fire only if there's an ajax error?

My intention is react to the request. If it has an error, I want to do something. If it's successful, I want to do something else, etc...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're passing the callbacks as part of the data to be posted, so they're getting evaluated as part of the post call.  Try this:

```
$.post(url, { comment: text }, function(data) {
        alert(data);    
});
```

or

```
$.ajax(url, { data: { comment: text },
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function() {
        alert("before send");
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("error"); 
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);    
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 Probably just OP's typo, but in fact he is not adding callbacks to the specific request, but adding their results to the data he is posting.

Comment: @Andrew, shouldn't it be `$.ajax({ url: url, comment: text` ? I tried your version and it's behaving erratically..

Comment: @Mohamad:  As of jQuery 1.5 the URL can be a separate parameter.  For prior versions it needs to be inside the settings as you suggest.  See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Andrew Cooper, thanks you are right. Problem: The comment data is not show up now! I don't think it;s getting posted anymore!

Comment: @Andrew Cooper, what I mean is, if I use $.post, comment is available in the params. With $.ajax, it's not!

Comment: @Mohamad - Sorry.  I forgot that you need to pass the data as an object.  You need to do `data: { comment: text },`.  I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The ".post()" method only allows for a single callback (for "success").  If you want to do what you're doing, you'll need to use "$.ajax()".

*edit* — Helpful downvoter @trey points out that (as of jQuery 1.5) the *return* value of the "$.post()" call will be an object to which other handlers can be added, including handlers for "error" (but **not** for "beforeSend").

Comment: @trey, you are not entirely correct.  It is possible to assign "success" handlers to the **return value** from "$.post()", but not passed in as a parameter, as the OP intends to do.

Comment: @trey - It seems that link only shows one callback for success

Comment: should have been more clear: `$.post("example.php", function() {
      alert("success");
    })
    .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
    .error(function() { alert("error"); })
    .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });` works

Comment: @trey yes, that's correct - but note that one of the "handlers" the OP wanted to use was "beforeSend", which will already have been called by the time that "$.post()" returns.

Comment: You're right about before send, what I was disagreeing with was your statement: The ".post()" method only allows for a single callback (for "success").

Comment: Well that's definitely true, though it's not really due to direct support by "$.post()" :-).  It just sort-of inherits the new "jqXhr" object features because it's basically just a wrapper around "$.ajax()" anyway.

Answer (score 2):

$.post only has one callback function. Try using $ instead as thats a lot more features.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

```
  $.post("example.php", { comment: "my comment" }, function() {
    alert("success"); })
    .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
    .error(function() { alert("error"); })
    .complete(function() { alert("complete");
  });
```

edit: added post data to callback

Comment: thank you. I'm curious, how do I pass my data to the function in your example?